# Non-square raster pixels created during TIN Interpolation?

Tags: raster, qgis-3, interpolation, tin, cell-size

I am trying to create a raster by using the TIN Interpolation tool in QGIS. I'm using a 3D polygon shapefile as input. I'm looking to create a raster of square pixels, although despite specifying a square output extent and 0.1m cell size, the resulting tif file contains cell size that are slightly non-square (e.g. 0.09999500000000000055,-0.09999750000000000305).

I've done this process many times before with no issue and can't understand why this is different. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: The difference between them in micrometer. (`0.1 - 0.0999950... = 0.000005 = 5 micron`). Not important. For example, if you run `0.1+0.2` in python console, you will get `0.30000000000000004`.  This may help: [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). Explanations in the link are about Python, but I think, it is similar for other languages, too. I guess it's nature of decimal number in programming realm.